# Elasticsearch Array

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have following values in my document.

"ReturnCode": [ "0", "0" ] 
"ReturnCode": [ "0", "1" ]

If I search 0,0 it should return 1st document and If I search 0,1 then it should return 2nd document. I am trying with following query but it's not giving correct result. Result must match with all array elements.

```
GET test/_search
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { 
          "terms": { "ReturnCode":[ "0","1"] }
        }
      ]

    }
  }
}
 }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Terms query is an OR query

```
    GET test/_search
    {
    "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { 
              "term": { "ReturnCode":"0"}
            },
            { 
              "term": { "ReturnCode":"1"}
            }      
         ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

You need to create individual term queries inside the must clause as above

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I am trying to search with 0,0 , it pulls 0.1 record too. when I am searching with 0.1 , it correctly pulls 1 record. do you know why ?

Comment: As returnCode is string, the default analyzer for the field is 'standard analyzer'. '0.1' gets tokenized into '0' and '1'. Hence, it matches both 0 and 1.

Comment: To avoid this, u cn either map it as a numeric field or set its mapping to not_analyzed or change the analyzer to keyword

Comment: Thanks buddy. Really appreciate for your help

Comment: I submitted new question , really appreciate if you can comment on that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364624/elasticsearch-group-by-having-aggs